# Integrating Ethereum with other systems (permissioned/permissionless)

Tags: blockchain-interoperation

If I would like to integrate Ethereum with other systems - permissioned or permissionless, how does one do that?
for example, if I would like Ethereum to talk to Hyperledger or R3 Cordo as an example, how does it work?

Comment: wouldn't it be useful for you if you could export all the blockchain data to SQL ?

Comment: by design, Ethereum blockchain is public, so you would have to restrict the access to it, and only after that create some permission system. But even restricted access not always works, and can lead to information leak. So encrypting data is your best option if you need privacy. But data encryption is not included in Ethereum.

Comment: And why would you need to integrate Ethereum with something else, isn't current functionality enough ?

Comment: Thanks Nulik. Many Enterprises would not have a single blockchain system when you fast forward in time (just like large enterprises have ERP systems from different vendors today). Hence the need for integration with other BC systems which could be public or private

Comment: I know how enterprises work, I have worked in one. My question is more of the kind: why current APIs are not enough for you to extract existing information ??? There is web3 javascript api that provides you almost any datum that you would need. Just point your 3rd party software to the IP of Ethereum node and that's it.

Answer (score 1):

To integrate Ethereum with any other blockchain (and especially any other non-blockchain such as Hyperledger) you have to have some sort of backend system which communicates with the Ethereum blockchain and your other system. It really doesn't make much of a difference what kind of system the other system is - it only affects how you communicate the *other* system, but Ethereum interactions stay basically the same.